# How to use count "how many times a particular customer made inquiries"?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, distinct-values

I have this table called "Anfrage". And these are the columns in "Anfrage Table":

[Anfrage Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhgk4.png)

I want to count how many times the same customer made inquiries. So I made a new column "Menge_Anfrage" which means number of inquiries. The result should be like this:

[Table Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EbMC.png)

I tried to use this query:

```
 `SELECT DISTINCT Count(*)
FROM Anfrage
WHERE KundenNr = 1
) AS "Menge Anfrage",`
```

but it returns a "4" in all rows in "Menge Anfrage" column. Could someone please tell me the right query? I'm using SQL Tools 1,8 b38. Thank you so much.

Comment: Bit confused. you have a clause `WHERE KundenNr = 1` but your table doesn't have such row ?

Comment: I was just randomly trying out the query. If I didn't put the where clause, it will return a "6" as the result, which is not what I wanted. Have you seen my Table Result? That's what I want.

Comment: I got it and I believe you have the answer now available :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to count the number of times KundenNr occurs. Your table doesn't need a new column added for this; you should calculate it every time in the query:

```
SELECT
  KundenNr,
  Project,
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY KundenNr) as Menge_Anfrage
FROM
  Anfrage
```

The query above is the equivalent of this query, that works in databases thatdo not support analytical functions:

```
SELECT
  a.KundenNr,
  a.Project,
  x.Menge_Anfrage
FROM
  Anfrage a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT KundenNr, COUNT(*) as Menge_Anfrage FROM Anfrage GROUP  BY KundenNr) x 
  ON a.KundenNr = x.KundenNr
```

`OVER(PARTITION BY KundenNr)` does pretty much what the bottom query's GROUP BY subquery does; it breaks the dataset into partitions (groups) based on different values of KundenNr and the COUNT(*) applies to the partition, not the whole dataset. Study and understand how the bottom query works, and then you should be able to understand the top one if you bear in mind that the join between a partitioned kundennr and the row from the table, is automatic.

Here's another way of writing the same thing:

```
SELECT
  a.KundenNr,
  a.Project,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Anfrage x WHERE x.KundenNr = a.KundenNr) as Menge_Anfrage
FROM
  Anfrage a
```

You could consider that oracle will, for every row in the output, run that subquery presented in the select. This is logically the equivalent of running a grouping query and then joining the results, or creating a partition hash table that maps KundenNr to Count and then matching them up when preparing the results

Comment: Yes, you get exactly what I mean. But your query didn't work out unfortunately. It gives error 
ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row  :(

Comment: It won't be my query that's giving that, it'll be whatever you've done with it. For example if you've used it in an insert like `INSERT INTO table (a,b) SELECT a,b,c FROM othertable` - this query selects 3 values but insert only specifies 2; "too many values" error results. As noted in the first line of my answer, you shouldn't store this count in a table, because then you've got to update it every time you add a row. Just calculate it when it is needed by running this query (with this extra `COUNT(*) OVER(...)` any time you want the up to date count

Comment: @ella widya, Don't replace the query somewhere as you may have done it seems what is being given but use this as the final solution.

Comment: @Caius Jard I didn't use any insert and now it returns error ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row.
What does this "OVER(PARTITION BY KundenNr)" do?

Comment: My first query doesn't use a subquery. My second query has a subquery that is joined and it is perfectly legal for such a query to return more than one row. *You're doing something else with query given in the answer, and you're doing it wrong*. "subquery returns more than one row" occurs on queries like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = (SELECT y FROM othertable)` where the subquery `SELECT y FROM othertable` returns more than one row. x cannot be simultaneously equal to more than one value

Comment: ps; it doesn't have to be an insert that returns "too many values", `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IN (SELECT a,b, FROM othertable)` will do it too; IN can only cope with the same number of values being selected on the right as are on the left.. For exmple `WHERE (x,y) IN (SELECT a,b ... FROM` is legal

Comment: @ellawidya I added some more info to the answer to address your *what is this OVER(...)* question